# Prolog, can't figure out how to get final value from function at base case

Tags: prolog

I'm not sure how to solve this error. `placePoly` works correctly and is eventually called with the result I desire in the last argument, but when I trace it in SWI Prolog it just backtracks to the beginning and doesn't return anything. Shouldn't it return once it hits the base case?

```
placePoly([],_,_,_) :- !.
placePoly([(X,Y)|T],Letter,Board,_) :- setPixel(X,Y,Letter,Board,NewBoard),
                                   placePoly(T,Letter,NewBoard,NewBoard).

setPixel(X,Y,Letter,P,NewP) :- getElement(Y,P,Row),
                           setElement(Y,NewRow,P,NewP),
                           setElement(X,Letter,Row,NewRow).
```

Comment: In the base case, the two last parameters should be the same, and you need to fix it appropriately in the recursive case (unless I am mistaken).

Comment: Also, you don't need the cut, as you are pattern matching on param one, and convering all the cases.

Comment: "function" -> "predicate". This is Prolog.